# Gradle Dependency of Dependency Substitution

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring-boot gradle project. It has a dependency of a dependency of a dependency that I cannot use for internal reasons. I've forked that module and published it to my repo with its own version number that I want to be used in my project.

Part of the dependency tree looks like:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.2
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:2.7.2
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.65
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.65
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.65
```

I need to force my project to use a custom version of those bottom two modules, let's call the new versions `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.65.CUSTOM` and `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.65.CUSTOM`.

I've never attempted this. I'm trying all different setups in my project's build.gradle file like

```
configurations { main }
configurations.main.resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
    substitute module('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.65') using module('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.65.CUSTOM')
    substitute module('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.65') using module('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.65.CUSTOM')
}
```

But the 9.0.65 versions keep getting injected. So my question(s) are:

- Am I using dependencySubstitution incorrectly, and where in the build.gradle should it be?
- Does dependencySubstitution work for dependencies of dependencies (ad nauseam), or only for direct dependencies?
- Short of forking all these dependencies to declare their dependencies, is there any way I can force my Gradle to *never* use version `9.0.65` and *only* ever use `9.0.65.CUSTOM` no matter its location in the dependency tree?

Comment: Maybe
`
configurations.main.resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.65.CUSTOM'
    force 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.65.CUSTOM'
}
`
If memory serves me.

Comment: That does not compile. Is shows error: "Could not find method force() for arguments [org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.65.CUSTOM] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.dependencysubstitution.DefaultDependencySubstitutions.". I am using Gradle version 6.8.1 by the way.

Comment: I wouldn't call this "dependency injection", nor tag it as such. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection for what's commonly understood by the term.

Comment: The manual has a recipe for this, I haven't tried it, but it may just work: https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:adding-constraints-transitive-deps

Comment: The biggest obstacle I think is that you create your own configuration ("main"), and make the substitution apply only there. `configurations.all` will include all the interesting configurations.

Comment: That fails with "Could not get unknown property 'resolutionStrategy' for ConfigurationInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectSet.". I'm not sure if I'm putting it in the right place but I tried in several locations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your configurations are setup properly and the coordinates for your custom modules are correct, you should be able to do

```
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            dependencySubstitution {
                substitute(module("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el")).with(module("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:9.0.65.CUSTOM"))
                substitute(module("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket")).with(module("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:9.0.65.CUSTOM"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would double check you have your repositories, configurations and that you are doing this dependency substitution in the module that needs to substitute the given modules for custom ones. Otherwise you may run into errors.